# Photoshop: Converting bitmap to shape

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop

I have a low res image with a S shape which I want to use. However due to the colors and the quality of the image i cannot get a good smooth edged selection or work path of the S shape in the image. What do I do?
I have tried magnetic lasso, magic wand tool and then sharpen edges. I have a pixellated s shape now , from which I want to extract a smooth edged vector/shape.

And this is what I have finally. The magic wand gives a jagged selection. the magnetic lasso is no better. is there an easy way?

[image: my image]

Comment: or is there an easy way i can create this design from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to do it manually, your best option is the **Pen tool**.  This will let you get the exact shape you want without having to worry about Photoshop trying to guess.  The pen tool is great for making rounded and smooth shapes just as you want them. There are plenty of tutorials on how to use the pen tool like [this](http://www.melissaclifton.com/tutorial-pentool.html) one.

Comment: thanks. tried the pen tool too. the edges don't seem refined if i go over the margins with the pen tool. looks like i will have to create a shape from a font.

Comment: @able Your image is probably too cloudy to do any other way.  I really think you should keep trying with the pen tool.  Try using more segmentation or less segmentation or using the various features of the pen tool (The pen tool can do a lot).  Keep trying and get better at the pen tool, because at the end of the day, you pretty much have to draw this by hand, and the Pen tool is what pros use to make shapes just like this in Photoshop.